# Anaconda Navigator Install RStudio Mac OS X

Tags: r, macos, anaconda, rstudio

I am using anaconda navigator to run R Studio. R Studio was recently updated to version 1.0.153. However, this version does not work on my computer (Mac OS Sierra). The program fails to run and a blank pop-up window is created every time I try to open it. When I downgrade back to 1.0.136 ("Sincere Pumpkin Patch") the program runs fine. How can I properly update the version?

I tried installing both through the GUI and using `conda install -c r rstudio` in the terminal. Neither method produces a working version of RStudio 1.0.153.

Comment: RStudio and Anaconda R do not work well together. I would recommend just using the CRAN-provided binaries of R if at all possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing a similar problem on Windows.  It appears the RStudio.exe binary is never installed.  Rolling back to version 1.0.136 allows the RStudio app to function, but you lose the Plot tab functionality.